# opencv face detection; where to place the 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'?

Tags: opencv

I'm new here. I have currently been doing some simple projects using opencv. My present project in opencv is face detection. I have the codes as stated below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade;
CvMemStorage            *storage;

void detectFaces( IplImage *img );

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{  
        CvCapture *capture;
IplImage  *frame;
int       key;
char      *filename = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename, 0, 0, 0 );
storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

assert( cascade && storage && capture );

cvNamedWindow( "video", 1 );

while( key != 'q' ) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    if( !frame ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot query frame!\n" );
        break;
    }

    cvFlip( frame, frame, -1 );
    frame->origin = 0;

    detectFaces( frame );

    key = cvWaitKey( 10 );
}

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "video" );
cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

return 0;
}

void detectFaces( IplImage *img )
{
int i;

CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(
        img,
        cascade,
        storage,
        1.1,
        3,
        0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
        cvSize( 40, 40 ) );

for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) {
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
    cvRectangle( img,
                 cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),
                 cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),
                 CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );
}

cvShowImage( "video", img );
}
```

What I'm stuck with right now is where should I place the xml file? My current directory for opencv2.1 is at C:/OpenCV2.1.

Can anyone help me with this matter? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading with this char *filename = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"; Then you need to put your xml file in the current directory. If it is in other directory, search for the folder instead like char *filename = "C://opencv//...haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application with by using its icon in Windows explorer, put the XML file right next to it.

If you are running from the commandline terminal, put the XML into your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Better to place the haar cascade file under:

First, put your Haar_cascade.xml file under the solution folder of your project (VS environment project folder)

**Steps:**
1. Right click on solutions file.
2. Click on option "Configuration Properties"
3. Click on debugging.
4. Under debugging. On the right hand side under **Command Arguments** give name of your cascade xml. For example haar_cascade_frontalface.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may use-

```
face_cascade.load("d:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
```

So that the code looks like-

```
/** @function main */
 int main( int argc, const char** argv )
 {
   CvCapture* capture;
   Mat frame;
   face_cascade.load("F:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
   eyes_cascade.load("F:\\haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml");
```

Comment: please, it's 2014 now. *stop* using the deprecated c-api.